# Workflow description and implementation in .Net

Tags: .net, azure, bpel, bpmn

Here is the situation:
We have to build a system made of web services as main components. Some web services will write data in databases, other receive a file as input and produce a transformed file as output, make validation on the file format...

Our idea is first to develop the basic components and then put them in a cloud (using Windows Azure).

The current problem is how will the web services communicate? Since our customers use a client application which communicates with a front end web service, what is the best solution to model and implement the business process or workflow in our future cloud?

I read some articles about BPMN, BPEL and YAWL but I don't know if these are good ways to start. And are they compatible with the service bus of Windows cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have solved the problem by now, but Windows Workflow would have been a fair choice for this application.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489441.aspx

This is the workflow language integrated into .NET, being its counterpart to BPEL, YAWL and all the others. As you can see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2011/01/12/running-net4-windows-workflows-in-azure-today.aspx runs in Azure.

This integration might get even stronger in .NET 4.5, see: https://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/72594

Comment: @wigy: Did you mean to say that the third link was broken? I replaced that one. Moreover, if you have a personal problem with Microsoft, then don't bother visiting questions about Microsoft technology.

Comment: I have no problem with Microsoft itself. I have problem with sites maintained by Microsoft. The links to them get rotten easier than a tomato.

Comment: @wigy: I aggree with you. Link rot really is a problem with microsoft sites. For this answer, they are the primary source, so there's unfortunately no better option.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Windows Azure AppFabric features http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/AppFabric/Overview/